# Adding parameters to ng-click in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

My code is something like this

### HTML view

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
  <button ng-click="get_user_detail(Andrew)"> 
  </button>

  <button ng-click="get_user_detail(Andrew1)"> 
  </button>
</div>
```

### AngularJS

```
   var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

   app.controller("myCtrl", ['$compile', '$http', '$scope', function ($compile, $http, $scope) {
     $scope.get_user_detail=function(name){
         var response = $http.get("myURL", {
            params: {user_id:12345,name:name}
        });
      response.success();
      response.error();
     }
 }]);
```

While I was working with one parameter user_id,it was working fine,parameters were passed properly to request.After I added 2nd parameter name,it is not getting passed in params.

Comment: What is Andrew and Andrew1? input? Scope's element?

Comment: Try putting name in quotations like `'Andrew'`. Otherwise it will look for key `Andrew` in `scope`.

Comment: Can you show us how you were trying to pass a second parameter.

Comment: Andrew and Andrew 1 are static string values ,Tried with quotation also.

Comment: In http.get request first param user_id is known..i.e. hardcoded here.Name I am receving from function arguments

Comment: your code should work fine if you add " " to the names, [look at this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/UolKiGos4F4YI8mskUuT?p=preview) I made with your code.

Answer (score 2):

Andrew is not a variable of your [`$scope`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$scope).

So when you do `get_user_detail(Andrew)`, the value of `Andrew` is **undefined**.

---

I guess you would like to pass it as a **static value** (string), put your value between quotes `' '`:

```
<button ng-click="get_user_detail('Andrew')">
```

Comment: @Groovy Could you explain what *not working* means? What is the behavior? Do you have any error?

Comment: Not any error. Not getting value of variable 'name' in function and it is not getting passed in params.

Answer (score 2):

As in the other answers, your code should work as long as you add `" "` to the strings you intend to pass as params.

```js
var app = angular.module('ngApp', []);

app.controller("myCtrl", ['$compile', '$http', '$scope', function ($compile, $http, $scope) {        
     
  $scope.get_user_detail = function(name){
     $scope.name = name
     // response = $http.get("myURL", {
     //     params: {user_id:12345,name:name}
     // });
     // response.success();
     // response.error();
   }
 }]);
```

```html
<div ng-app="ngApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  You clicked {{name}} <br/>
  <button ng-click="get_user_detail('Andrew')"> Andrew
  </button>

  <button ng-click="get_user_detail('Bob')"> Bob
  </button>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>

</div>
```

I commented the `$http` call for obvious reasons. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You must have string in ng-click in ' ':

```
<button ng-click="get_user_detail('Andrew')">
```

and in js code - *name* put in ' '

```
params: {user_id:12345,'name':name}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought you not define variables in controller, define variable with $scope

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
  <button ng-click="get_user_detail(Andrew)"> 
  </button>

  <button ng-click="get_user_detail(Andrew1)"> 
  </button>
</div>
```

Controller Code

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

   app.controller("myCtrl", ['$compile', '$http', '$scope', function    ($compile, $http, $scope) {
     $scope.Andrew = 'John';
     $scope.Andrew = 'Jam';
     $scope.get_user_detail=function(name){
         var response = $http.get("myURL", {
            params: {user_id:12345,name:name}
        });
      response.success();
      response.error();
     }
 }]);
```

Other soluation you can direct pass string without define variable

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
  <button ng-click="get_user_detail('Andrew')"> 
  </button>

  <button ng-click="get_user_detail('Andrew1')"> 
  </button>
</div>
```